# Calculate sum value jQuery PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database

I have a problem calculating the sum of the data from the database and from user input, can Y'all help me?

this is the PHP code

1st value (stok di database) is data from database, and 2nd value (stok fisik) is data from user input, and selisih is 2nd value - 1st value.

```
        <div class="box-content nopadding" style="overflow: auto;">

            <table width="400px" class="table table-hover table-nomargin table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="2">No</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="2">Nama Barang</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;" colspan="2">Stok</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;" rowspan="2">Selisih</th>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Stok di Database</th>
                        <th style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;">Stok Fisik</th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <?php
                        $data = $db->query("select id, nama_barang, stock from tbl_atk group by nama_barang");
                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++) {
                            $no = $i + 1;
                            if ($no % 2 ==0) $bg ='#FBFBFB';
                            else $bg = '#FFFFFF';
                            // $total = 'result' - $data[$i]['stock'];
                            $tot_masuk = $tot_masuk + "stock_op";
                            $tot_keluar = $tot_keluar + $data[$i]['stock'];
                            $grand_tot = $tot_masuk - $tot_keluar;

                    ?>

                    <tr>
                        <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;"><?php echo $no; ?></td>

                        <td><?php echo $data[$i]['nama_barang']?></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right;" class="so"><?php echo $data[$i]['stock']; ?></td>

                        <td><input type="number" class="form-control so" id="stock_op" name="stock_op" style="text-align: left"></td>

                        <td style="text-align: right; font-weight:bold;"><output class="result"></output></td>
                    </tr>
                    <?php                                           
                    }
                ?>
    <script src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).on('input','.so',function(){
            var totalSum = 0;
            var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
            currentRow.find('.so').each(function(){
                var inputVal = ($(this).is('input')) ? $(this).val() : parseInt($(this).html());
                console.log(inputVal);
                if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                    totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
        }
    });
    currentRow.find('.result').val(totalSum);
});
    </script>
                <tr style="background-color:#eaeaea; font-weight:bold;">
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">Selisih</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $tot_keluar; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $tot_masuk; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $grand_tot; ?></td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>

        </div>
```

and this is the [User Interface](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgSHg.png)

Comment: You should not put `.` in class name.
`<td style="text-align: right;" class="form-control .so"><?php echo $data[$i]['stock']; ?></td>`
change `.so` to `so` on this line

Comment: @CodeThing still not working.. can you help me out?

Comment: On input change, are you trying to sum the value of 3rd & 4th column of each row and then update the 5th column? Is that right?

Comment: The line `$tot_masuk = $tot_masuk + 'stock_op';` makes no sense to me, or am I missing something?

Comment: The `.form-group` class, There is no such element present in your HTML. How you expect the jquery code to run?

Comment: @CodeThing that's right.

Comment: @Jamie_D that's for sum the entire 4th row

Comment: @Fauzio I looks like you're  adding the string "stock_op". 'stock_op' is not a variable.

Comment: @CodeThing I already put form-group but the result is not that I want..

Comment: @Fauzio Check below answer. Also what Jamie_D is saying makes sense. You just can't add string and value.

Comment: @CodeThing I did, but still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `.so` to `so` in the below input fields.

```
<td style="text-align: right;" class="form-control .so"><?php echo $data[$i]['stock']; ?></td>
<td><input type="number" class="form-control .so" id="stock_op" name="stock_op" style="text-align: left"></td>
```

Change id result to class result in below line

```
<td style="text-align: right; font-weight:bold;"><output id="result"></output></td>
```

*New Update*

Give a specific class to your stok fisik cell

```
<tr style="background-color:#eaeaea; font-weight:bold;">
                    <td style="text-align: center; vertical-align:middle;"></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;">Selisih</td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $tot_keluar; ?></td>
                        <td class="grandResult" style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $tot_masuk; ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: right;"><?php echo $grand_tot; ?></td>
                </tr>
```

change your jquery code to this

```
    $(document).on('input','.so',function(){
var grandSum = 0;
        var totalSum = 0;
        var currentRow = $(this).closest('tr');
        currentRow.find('.so').each(function(){
            var inputVal = ($(this).is('input')) ? $(this).val() : parseInt($(this).html());
            if($.isNumeric(inputVal)){
                totalSum += parseFloat(inputVal);
            }
        });
        currentRow.find('.result').val(totalSum);

$('input.so').each(function(){
            var cVal = ($(this).is('input')) ? $(this).val() : parseInt($(this).html());
            if($.isNumeric(cVal)){
                grandSum += parseFloat(cVal);
            }
        });
        $('.grandResult').val(grandSum);
    });
```

Comment: it's work, mate, thx. but how about sum for the entire 4th row?

Comment: @Fauzio You mean you want to sum all the calculated values in the 4th column? Where you want to display this total?

Comment: yes, I mean 4th column, between 2396 and -2396. below 'stok fisik' column. https://i.stack.imgur.com/WgSHg.png

Comment: *stok fisik cell, I mean.

Comment: It doesn't work, mate. can I have your email? I think it will be better if we move to email. I need you.

Comment: @Fauzio Sorry, can't be on the email. You are close, you just need to loop through your inputs and sum the amount.
Instead of `$('input.so').each(function(){` Try `$('input[name="stock_op"]').each(function(){`. Hope this helps.

Comment: ok thank you so much, bro, its work, turns out I made a typo. I try `$grand_tot = $data[$i]['grandResult'] - $tot_keluar;` for cell under selisih -2396. It should be a subtraction between two cell on the left (grandResult and $tot_keluar) but it doesn't work. can you figured out once more?

Comment: hello, how if I want to subtract (-) instead of add (+)?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Fauzio, I have created a sample table with 3 columns,
    
 1. t_id (ie. id )
    
 2. t_name ( ie name barang)
    
 3. t_value (ie stock di database)
    
    
 I created a table and displayed the values of each rows in the table. all values from column t_value is added in java script array. then as user enters the value for that particular row.
    
    
 On click of the button , the value for that particular row is picked from db_column and user column and the result is printed in the result column

```
<?php
     $sql = "SELECT t_id,t_name, t_value FROM test_table";
                $result = $conn->query($sql);
                if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                    // output data of each row
                    $main_array = array();
                    $count=0;
                    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {?>
                <tr>
                    <td class="no">

                        <?php  echo $count;?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="name">

                        <?php  echo $row["t_name"]."<br>";?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="db_value">
                        <?php 
                                  array_push($main_array,$row["t_value"]);
                                  echo $row["t_value"]."<br>";?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="user_value">
                        <form method="post">
                            <input type="number" value="">
                            <button id="cal" type="button" class="<?php echo $count;?>"> Calculate </button>
                        </form>
                    </td>
                    <td class="result">
                        <input type="tel" name="" value="" id="result_<?php echo $count;?>">
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <?php $count++;}?>

        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var main_array = new Array();
        <?php foreach($main_array as $key => $val){ ?>
        main_array.push('<?php echo $val; ?>');
        <?php } ?>
        jQuery('#cal').on('click', function() {
            id = jQuery(this).attr('class');
            value_1st = main_array[id];
            value_2nd = jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('.user_value')).find('input[type="number"]').val();
            result = value_1st + value_2nd;
            input_field = jQuery(jQuery(jQuery(this).closest('.user_value')).next()).find('#result_' + id);
            input_field.val(result);

        });
    });
</script>
```

[image]